# tvOS Framework contains incomplete bitcode

Tags: tvos, bitcode

I have a project with the following configuration for tvOS:

**MyApp**

**MyAppFramework**

**MyAppFramework** is set to be embedded in **MyApp**.

The app runs fine in debug on the device, but when submitting to the App Store after Archiving I get:

> **ERROR ITMS-90668**: "Invalid Bundle Executable. The executable file 'MyApp.app/Frameworks/MyAppFramework.framework/MyAppFramework'
>   contains incomplete bitcode. To compile binaries with complete
>   bitcode, open Xcode and choose Archive in the Product menu."
>
> **ERROR ITMS-90635**: "Invalid Mach-O Format. The Mach-O in bundle "MyApp.app/Frameworks/MyAppFramework.framework" isn’t consistent with
>   the Mach-O in the main bundle. The main bundle Mach-O contains
>   arm64(bitcode and machine code), while the nested bundle Mach-O
>   contains arm64(machine code). Verify that all of the targets for a
>   platform have a consistent value for the ENABLE_BITCODE build
>   setting."

Neither the MyApp or MyAppFramework has any configuration setting for BITCODE, so it's taking whatever the default is.

Is anyone else experiencing this issue, any ideas?

Comment: And you've double-checked the ENABLE_BITCODE build settings and tried a clean and archive again?  Watch the build log as it builds and check that `-fembed-bitcode` is being passed to the compiler for both targets.

Comment: Hi, There is no ENABLE_BITCODE option in the project setting anywhere, I even checked the pbxproj file...but that setting does not exist. This is a new project. I even created a new project in Xcode and that setting is no-longer present.

Comment: It's under *Build Options* and it's called *Enable Bitcode*.

Comment: Not for me :-(. This is a new TVOS project. TVOS -> Application -> Single View Application

Comment: I may have solved it: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/47757

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I was building a framework and using that in my app. What I needed to do was archive the framework instead. This solved the ITMS-90635 error.